# The Boundaries of UI State and Application State

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have trouble coming up or finding the boundaries of the so called ["UI State"](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/906140844574601216).

Imagine the example of an issue tracker:

We have a list of "issue cards", which each contain:

1. A simple icon that represents the progress (i.e. open, closed)
2. The description text of the issue (a simple `<p/>` element)
3. A **single** Action button that changes d =epending on the state of the issue: "Assign to myself" or "Mark as done".
4. A button that opens a context menu (AKA right-click menu). This menu has a list of a variety of action buttons. Depending on the
   state, some actions are greyed out and can not be clicked / or are
   just not shown. Like "Close Case", if the case is already closed.

If you could categorize each of these items into UI-State vs. Application State, it would help me understand the boundaries.

**More practically**: How would you divide this little example application into [containers and presentational components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0)?

**My interpretation**: 1. and 2. are just presentational, 3. and 4. are stateful. Is this right? How would I structure this as containers and components?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of listed examples are examples of *application state*, where UI is determined by persistent data that is received from the backend.

*UI state* usually refers to UI component local state that is determined by user actions, e.g. window position, active tab, unsubmitted form values, etc. Depending on the case, UI state may be lifted up and stored somewhere (persistent storage or URL) or be discarded.

Comment: Thank you. This helped understand the definition of UI State. How would you structure the mentioned example when it comes to container vs component?

Comment: Thanks. I'm not trying to pressure you, but did you notice that I added a question to my comment? I think SO doesn't notify on editing of comments.

 The question of how to structure components and containers. If you could answer it on the basis of my issue tracker example or point me to literature.

Comment: No, the update wasn't shown at the moment when I posted mine. All the state you described belongs to parent smart component, while dumb UI components should receive data through props to be shown, at least that's how I imagine this. This is the state https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/906140844574601216 talks about because it likely originates from fetched data.

Comment: Thanks a lot estus

Answer (score 0):

if I want to implement this project I would act like this :

1. a component for managing all children components
2. a store to managing model, data and fields
3. a component for displaying icon and description text and button
4. a component for context menu

please consider that if you are using MVVM pattern, be sure that all responsibilities of actions are done by store and for changing some properties use `observable` fields
and if not use state in manager component and pass via proprs in children.